# Uninitialized memory warning on structs instantiated with new

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

So I have a Node struct

```
struct Node
{
    int x = 0;
};
```

I make 20 `Node*`s. My understanding is that `Node**` is a pointer to the start of an array that holds pointers to `Node`s.

```
constexpr int mazeSize = 20;
Node** testMaze = new Node * [mazeSize];
```

After this, I started getting warnings and errors when I tried to do anything with it. Examples:

```
testMaze[0]->position.x == 0; //->Using uninitialized memory `*testMaze` and
```

What I understood from this error: `*testMaze` is dereferencing the array of pointers, which means it's referring to the first `Node` object in that array. If this is the case than how would I initialize it? If I simply created the `Node*` as so:

```
Node* node = new Node;
node->x = 0;
```

Than it works fine and there is no need to initialize it, so why not with the way I am doing it? I also don't understand how to initialize a struct.

Another examlpe:

```
testMaze[0]->x == testMaze[1]->x //->Runtime error: Access violation reading error
testMaze[0]->x = 0; //->Runtime error: Access violation writing error
```

How can I fix these problems? Thanks.

Comment: `new Node * [mazeSize];` provides an array of pointers. You haven't shown any code that points those pointers anywhere valid, and the warning message suggests that you didn't  write such code. Pointer's gonna point, so the solution is create a few `Node`s and start pointing.

Comment: A `Note*` is not a `Node`. You have pointers but no `Node` to point to. You probably meant to use `new Node[mazesize]` to actually create `Node` objects but you should just use `std::vector<Node>` instead.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah I think I understand now. I thought `new Node * [mazeSize];` would give me pointers with nodes created and pointed to by those pointers, but it actually only makes the pointers and I have to create the nodes myself and get those pointer to point to those nodes. Is that it?

Comment: @user4581301 Just tried it and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Groovy. Glad to help. Now see if you can use what @FrançoisAndrieux talks about and kill all of the (visible) pointers dead. Pointers almost always slow down code because the computer can't just get the next bit of data, it has to use the pointer to track it down and then load it. But if all of the data is on one straight line, the computer just starts loading stuff in the background and the second item is probably already ready for use by the time you need it if not grabbed in the same read that loaded the first one.

Comment: Unrelated ranting: Computers are smart because they can do incredible numbers of stupid things very fast. A lot of the time you get more from letting the computer be stupid and fast than you get from making the computer be smarter. For short runs of data, an O(N) linear search is far faster than any of the fancy O(log(N)) searches because the CPU can just go nope.nope.nope.nope.nope... and not have to make any decisions about the correct path to take or what data to load next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember that pointer types are separate, concrete types with their own type and size. A pointer to T `T*` basically boils down to a small chunk of memory that is used to store an address to another memory area, which (hopefully) contains an instance of some type `T`.

With

`Node** testMaze = new Node * [mazeSize];`

you are allocating an array of `maxSize` *pointer sized* elements of type `Node*` and `sizeof(Node*)` (which on modern platforms is usually 4 or 8 bytes, depending if your executable is meant to run in 32 bit or 64 bit mode).

These newly created pointers are not initialized, and thus point to invalid addresses, unless you also *zero initialize* the array:

```cpp
Node** testMaze = new Node * [mazeSize] {};
assert (testMaze[0] == nullptr); // holds true
```

In order to get an `maxSize` instances of `Node`, you have to, well, create `maxSize` instances of `Node`:

```cpp
Node** testMaze = new Node* [mazeSize];
for (std::ptrdiff_t i {}; i < maxSize; ++i) {
    testMaze[i] = new Node { /* insert parameters here */ };
}
```

Given that you are using `constexpr`, I infer the revision of C++ you are targeting is C++11 or newer. In this case, you should be aware that `operator new` and `operator new[]` are almost always the wrong choice when writing modern C++, given that they only returns pointers whose ownership and lifetime you then have to manage by hand.

You most definitely should start using STL containers, such as `std::vector` and `std::array`, which are easier to use and can avoid you a great deal of unnecessary pain. If you insist on using `new`, at least give a look to `std::unique_ptr`, which wraps a pointer or C array and automatically calls `delete` or `delete[]` as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: You don't want `testMaze[0] = new Node`, you want `testMaze[i] = new Node`. A subtle but important difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom Dumb me, I made a classic copy-paste mistake. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: Often when you use `std::vector` you don't need pointers at all, you can make each element of the vector be the full object.

Comment: @MarkRansom one reason why someone might prefer using a vector of (preferrably smart) pointers instead of just vector<T> is when your T is _very_ large and you need to sort the vector or in general change the order of its elements. Swapping `unique_ptr`s is instantaneous, while frequently `memcpy`-ing massively large data structures could turn out being much slower.

Comment: Swapping pointers is damn fast compared to copying objects, but statistically speaking, you don't do nearly as much of it as you do iterating through the list of pointed-at objects, and to speed up the less-common use case, you've slowed down the more-common use case by something like an order of magnitude. That's a sucker bet. You'll lose a lot more than you'll win. If you know the use case is to frequently shuffle the data around and rarely look at the data, use pointers. Every other time, avoid the pointer.

Comment: That's where linked lists usually get killed. Sure, you have O(1) insert and delete, but everything else you do, including finding where in the list to insert or delete, is O(N) made painfully slow by by cache misses and pointer chasing.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree. In my experience, linked lists are basically almost always worse than just using vectors, and even when you need to erase elements from the middle they are not worth the hassle because copying memory is something modern CPUs are very good at. That's why I underlined the fact that T should be _very_ large to justify using a vector of pointers, without even mentioning how inconvenient is using pointers instead of values.

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

```
    constexpr int mazeSize = 20;
    Node** testMaze = new Node *[mazeSize]; //this makes 20 pointers, but the pointers dont point to anything
```

```
    testMaze[0]->position.x == 0; //undefined, as testMaze's pointers do not point to anything
```

This works because you make a new `node`, not a new pointer to a pointer to a `node`.

```
Node * node = new Node;
node->x = 0;
```

As for this:

```
    testMaze[0]->x == testMaze[1]->x; //This is an undefined pointer, it doesn't point to anything, and you are trying to access it, so UNDEFINED behavior
    testMaze[0]->x = 0; //This is a undefined pointer, it doesn't point to anything, and you are trying to access it, so UNDEFINED behavior
}
```

I would just do this:

```
Node** Make(int size) {
    Node** temp = new Node * [size];
    Node* pool = new Node[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        temp[i] = &pool[i];
    }
}
```

This makes your array of pointers, makes your pointers point to actual pointers which point to actual values.

Also, don't forget to `delete[]` your `Node**`s and `Node*`s, or you'll have a memory leak!

Comment: Note also that the manual memory management involved can trip you up almost countless ways. Did I allocate? Is there an allocation already there that needs to be dealt with? is it time to delete? Is it safe to delete? Who's job is it to delete, anyway? What sort of copying logic do I need? Can I simply copy the pointer and share the allocation or do I need a new allocation and copy what's at the pointer? You know how the masters deal with the problem? By almost never facing it. [They'll do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).